# Need help constructing a Long loop(long x, int n) function in C given 64 bit assembly instructions

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, att

I have the following assembly code from the C function `long loop(long x, int n)`
with x in `%rdi`, n in `%esi` on a 64 bit machine. I've written my comments on what I think the assembly instructions are doing.

```
loop:

    movl   %esi, %ecx // store the value of n in register ecx
    movl   $1, %edx // store the value of 1 in register edx (rdx).initial mask
    movl   $0, %eax //store the value of 0 in register eax (rax). this is initial return value 
    jmp    .L2 

.L3 

    movq   %rdi, %r8 //store the value of x in register r8  
    andq    %rdx, %r8 //store the value of (x & mask) in r8
    orq    %r8, %rax //update the return value rax by (x & mask | [rax] ) 
    salq   %cl, %rdx //update the mask rdx by ( [rdx] << n)

.L2 

    testq  %rdx, %rdx //test mask&mask
    jne    .L3 // if (mask&mask) != 0, jump to L3    
    rep; ret
```

I have the following C function which needs to correspond to the assembly code:

```
    long loop(long x, int n){
          long result = _____ ;   
          long mask; 
       // for (mask = ______; mask ________; mask = ______){ // filled in as:
          for (mask = 1;      mask != 0;     mask <<n) {
              result |= ________;
          } 
          return result;
     }
```

I need some help filling in the blanks, I'm not a 100% sure what the assembly instructions but I've given it my best shot by commenting with each line.

Comment: We are no "do my homework" site. Ask your teacher for advice.

Comment: Step 1 in these exercises is to guess which variables are in which registers. One thing to be aware of is that the return value from the function ends up in the `rax` register.

Comment: Sorry I'm not asking you to do my homework. I just added comments to what I think is going on with each instruction. I need help bridging this to the C code.

Comment: The `test` instruction is mainly for setting the flags for the benefit of the following branch instruction. So although technically the `test` is doing `mask & mask`, the equivalent C code is just `mask != 0`.

Comment: The comment after the `orq` instruction is not quite right. You should look at that again.

Comment: Thanks, I just corrected the comment after the orq instruction.

Comment: And what's in `rax`?

Comment: Initially rax will contain 0, I'm not sure what will happen after the orq statement in the assembly instructions

Comment: The last part of the `for` loop should be `mask <<= n`. So the last remaining question is, what variable is in `rax`?

Answer (score 3):

You've pretty much got it in your comments.

```c
long loop(long x, long n) {
    long result = 0;
    long mask;
    for (mask = 1; mask != 0; mask <<= n) {
        result |= (x & mask);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Because `result` is the return value, and the return value is stored in `%rax`, `movl $0, %eax` loads 0 into `result` initially.

Inside the for loop, `%r8` holds the value that is or'd with `result`, which, like you mentioned in your comments, is just `x & mask`.

Answer (score 0):

The function copies every `n`th bit to `result`.

**For the record, the implementation is full of missed optimizations**, especially if we're tuning for Sandybridge-family where `bts reg,reg` is only 1 uop with 1c latency, but `shl %cl` is 3 uops.  (BTS is also 1 uop on Intel P6 / Atom / Silvermont CPUs)

`bts` is only 2 uops on AMD K8/Bulldozer/Zen.  BTS reg,reg masks the shift count the same way x86 integer shifts do, so `bts %rdx, %rax` implements `rax |= 1ULL << (rdx&0x3f)`.  i.e. setting bit `n` in RAX.

(This code is clearly designed to be simple to understand, and doesn't even use the most well-known x86 peephole optimization, `xor`-zeroing, but it's fun to see how we can implement the same thing efficiently.)

**More obviously, doing the `and` inside the loop is bad**.  Instead we can just build up a mask with every `n`th bit set, and return `x & mask`.  This has the added advantage that with a non-`ret` instruction following the conditional branch, we don't need the `rep` prefix as padding for the `ret` even if we care about tuning for the branch predictors in AMD Phenom CPUs.  (Because it isn't the first byte after a conditional branch.)

```
# x86-64 System V:  x in RDI,  n in ESI
mask_bitstride:                      # give the function a meaningful name
    mov    $1, %eax                  # mask = 1
    mov    %esi, %ecx                # unsigned bitidx = n   (new tmp var)

# the loop always runs at least 1 iteration, so just fall into it
.Lloop:                     # do {
    bts    %rcx, %rax                # rax |= 1ULL << bitidx
    add    %esi, %ecx                # bitidx += n
    cmp    $63, %ecx                 # sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT - 1
    jbe    .Lloop           # }while(bitidx <= maxbit);  // unsigned condition

    and    %rdi, %rax       # return x & mask
    ret                # not following a JCC so no need for a REP prefix even on K10
```

We assume `n` is in the 0..63 range because otherwise the C would have undefined behaviour.  In that case, this implementation differs from the shift-based implementation in the question.  The `shl` version would treat `n==64` as an infinite loop, because shift count = `0x40 & 0x3f = 0`, so `mask` would never change.  This `bitidx += n` version would exit after the first iteration, because `idx` immediately becomes >=63, i.e. out of range.

A less extreme case is that `n=65` would copy all the bits (shift count of 1); this would copy only the low bit.

Both versions create an infinite loop for `n=0`.  I used an unsigned compare so negative `n` will exit the loop promptly.

---

On Intel Sandybridge-family, the inner loop in the original is 7 uops.  (mov = 1 + and=1 + or=1 + variable-count-shl=3 + macro-fused test+jcc=1).  This will bottleneck on the front-end, or on ALU throughput on SnB/IvB.

My version is only 3 uops, and can run about twice as fast.  (1 iteration per clock.)